# Upload Images in loop and data into 2 tables with 1 unique id

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am a little confused about the flow of this sql query but what i am trying to achieve is below.

1.) User submit a form from html
2.) The form contains a few varchar fields(variables) and images(the number of images can vary from 0 to 10 or max). 
3.) The form is submitted to a php, the fields are insert into a table(list) in 1 row, and the images are validated, then uploaded into server and the name of pics are inserted into a table listpic, all the images and the fields have the same id(so when used, the image can be pulled with the same id).

I am not very sure on how to insert both table with the same id, do i use sqli insert id autocrement id or do i use mysqli_insert_id()? And the images arent being uploaded as well.

Below are the codes that i have done

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

 $userid=$_SESSION['id'];


 //get form data


 $country = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['country']));
 $Location = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Location']));
$notes = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['notes']));
 $Status = "Open";


 if (!$country!$Location)
    die ("Please fill out all fields"); 
    else 




    if(!empty($_FILES)){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES);$i++)
    {
$supported_image = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png');


$path = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if ((!in_array($ext, $supported_image) )&&($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 1000000))

echo "Picture[$i]". "either empty or File format incorrect, You can change the pictures later<br>";

else{

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    if (file_exists("/Bootstraptest/image" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]))
      {
      die($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " already exists please add another file, or change the name ");
      }

    else

      {
        $photo=$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],
      "Bootstraptest/rent/$photo");
      echo $photo."&nbsp&nbspadded</br>";
        $photo1=$_FILES["file"]["name"];




              mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Listing (country,userid,username,Location,Status,notes) VALUES('$country','$userid','$username','$Location''$Status','$notes');") or die(mysqli_error($con));

          mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO listingpic (pic,userid) VALUES('$photo1',$userid;") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
      }
    }}}
    else{
                      mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Listing (country,userid,username,Location,Status,notes) VALUES('$country','$userid','$username','$Location','$Status','$notes');") or die(mysqli_error($con));


    }
















?>
```

HTML

Upload image form

```
<form id="submitform" class="form-horizontal" action='http://test.info/Bootstraptest/submitlisting.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And the part where the upload image button is.

```
 <div class="control-group">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                  <div class="controls">

                </div>
                </div>


  <!-- Button -->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
              <div class="controls">

                <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Send File" name="signin" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100px;">Submit</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:100px;">Close</button>

              </div>
```

Comment: Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the opening tag? Also check your file permissions

Comment: You would insert the form information into the first table then set an `$form_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id();` then insert your images with that relational id.

Comment: Hi JD no my form doesnt have that, what does the enctype do?

Comment: I see that it is adding the list, but it isnt adding the image part. I edited the question to include the part where the HTML form and upload part is

Comment: @Clarklight Have a look at the note in the [manual page to uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php): **Note: Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.**

Comment: I checked the php manual not sure why it won't load the form, i added the enctype as well. I was able to load it before but i added the Bootstrap on top, and can't do it now.

Comment: I tried removing the if statement(if !empty($_FILES) part) to just test the uploading image part, and that i make sure i select an image, so i can isolate the problem. But it is not running the php at all if i removed the if statement. I am thinking the images arent being passed from html to php.

Comment: I am not sure if the for loop statement supposed to be this for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]);$i++) because it gives me an error Notice: Undefined index: file in